# Proposed tag rename: [cryptmethod] => [encryption]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [cryptmethod](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptmethod) tag is currently used in four questions, but seems a bit overspecific: although all four questions *mention* the `'cryptmethod'` setting, only two of them are really *about* it. (In fact, the other two seem to be mistaken about what the setting actually does.)

The name of the Vim feature is "encryption", which covers these four questions and others which may not mention `'cryptmethod'` specifically.

I think the questions should be retagged with [encryption](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption), and then, possibly, [cryptmethod](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptmethod) should be added as a tag synonym for [encryption](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encryption).

I could do this myself, but wanted to check if others agree before doing so.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be fully in favor of this. The way I see it, a tag for [cryptmethod](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptmethod) is a little bit of a red-herring. The actual *setting* of `'cryptmethod'` is pretty much irrelevant, it's a question about how to use vim to encrypt files.

A parallel situation would be using the tag [shiftwidth](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shiftwidth) for questions about indentation. Nobody really has a question about the setting `'shiftwidth'`, but they are using that setting to achieve something related to  [indentation](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indentation), so that is the more appropriate tag.

Just like you, I could probably make the edits myself, but I'll wait to see if this answer is well-received before taking any action. We'd probably need some other user or a mod to be able to setup the synonym